# CMS login redirect to LMS dashboard after add SSL in Open edX

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, openedx

I am trying to add SSL in Open edX (Ironwood).

As you know, In the Ironwood version, We can login CMS by using LMS login.

Suppose that,
LMS URL - https://lms.mydomain.com
CMS URL - https://studio.mydomain.com

When I click on the CMS login button it redirects to LMS (https://lms.mydomain.com/login?next=https%3A%2F%2Fstudio.mydomain.com%2F) URL.

After login, it is redirecting to https://lms.mydomain.com/dashboard. Rather it should have redirected to this URL https://studio.mydomain.com/home

It is working properly without using SSL and Domain.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it by editing
`lms.env.json` and `cms.env.json` to have the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `".mydomain.com"`.

Also make sure `LOGIN_REDIRECT_WHITELIST` is set to `"studio.mydomain.com"`

Remember to restart the LMS and CMS.

```
/edx/bin/supervisorctl restart lms
/edx/bin/supervisorctl restart cms
/edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp_worker:
```